# Dynamic filters for auctions search engine MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
TABLE1 (Values)
ID|AUCTION_ID|VALUE_TYPE|VALUE
1|1|726|a
2|1|270|b
3|2|726|a
4|2|270|b
5|3|726|a
6|3|270|b
7|4|983|z
8|4|822|a

TABLE2 (Auctions)
ID|TITLE|DSC|PRICE
1|xxx|xxxxxxxxx|xxx
2|xxx|xxxxxxxxx|xxx
3|xxx|xxxxxxxxx|xxx
4|xxx|xxxxxxxxx|xxx
```

And now, how to select * from TABLE2 where ID in ( Select AUCTION_ID from Table1 where (`value_type` = 726 and `value` = 'a') AND (`value_type` = 270 and `value` = 'b')

SO query effect should be Auctions with ID are : 1 and 2.

HOW TO DO IT BY ONE SQL QUERY OR IN PHP?

PS.

THIS QUERY IS WORKING : 
SELECT `ID` FROM `table` WHERE `value` IN('a', 'b', 'c') GROUP BY `ID` HAVING COUNT(`ID`) >= 3;

BUT THIS SUSPEND THE SERVER :
Select * from Table_dane where (1 = 1) and `id` in (SELECT `ID` FROM `table` WHERE `value` IN('a', 'b', 'c') GROUP BY `ID` HAVING COUNT(`ID`) >= 3)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `exists`.  Twice:

```
select t2.*
from TABLE2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from Table1 t1
              where t2.id = t1.AUCTION_ID and t1.value_type = 726 and t1.value = 'a'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from Table1 t1
              where t2.id = t1.AUCTION_ID and t1.value_type = 270 and t1.value = 'b'
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `table1(auction_id, value_type, value)`.